# Java, CSV, Getting error if do not click on Save button of the csv file

Tags: java, csv

This is my code

```
    public double myMethod(String name)
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        String path = "/Users/T/Desktop/Training/MyFolder/";
        int maxColumn = 0;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        ArrayList findMaxColumn = new ArrayList();
        String line = ""; 
        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+name));
            while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                findMaxColumn.add(temp.split(",").length); 
            }
            maxColumn = getMaxNumber(findMaxColumn);
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path+name));
            List<String[]> myData =  reader.readAll();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < maxColumn;i++)
            {
                for (String[] lineData : myData) 
                {
                    String value= lineData[i];
```

The problem is, I have a csv file (generated from other method and stored in MyFolder) and when I run this code, I got an error "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" at  String value= lineData[i]. But,  if I open my csv file and click on save button (or make some changes for a value eg 0 to 1 etc) and close it **before** I run this code then it will be fine when I run it. That's weird!!! Could anyone explain to me why I have to open the csv file and make some changes(just  click on save button or change a value to another) to ignore the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your encoding when you save the file is the same encoding with the one you use when you read the file. It may well be that you are saving, for example, in UTF8 and reading the file as it would be UTF16.

This fits what you describe (if opening and saving the file before reading it, then it works) as well as the ""ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"" - showing that the "split" method did not find any separator (the comma) thus return a single string.

It would also help if using a debugger to check what is in your array just-to-be-added-to `findMaxColumn`  after splitting. Easier to debug if you use a local variable to store the result of `split` before adding:

```
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            String splitResult[]=temp.split(","); // easier to examine
            findMaxColumn.add(splitResult); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replied. I will check my encoding part now and lets you know.